# Vim Syntax Highlighting for an Object's Method Call

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I would like an object method call to be syntax highlighted in Vim. For instance, in an expression that contains `person.getName()`, I would like to match `getName` and give it some syntax highlighting.

I have tried quite a number of patterns and at the moment, this is what I have in my experimental syntax file;

```
" :set iskeyword+=.
syntax match myMatch "\v\.\zs\w+\ze\(" 
highlight link myMatch Function
```

It is not highlighting unless I comment in the first line above or issue `:set iskeyword+=.` manually and then try editing the file.

How can I make the highlighting successful without having to set `.` as part of `iskeyword`??

UPDATE: I have Pathogen and I have the file with the contents above in `~/.vim/bundle/vim-javascript-syn/syntax/javascript.vim`

Comment: Please extend you question and name the language/filetype you work with.

Comment: @Ralf, please check some updated details in the question.

Comment: 1) The file is `javascript.vim`, not `javascript.js`, or? 2) put the two lines in the file `~/.vim/after/syntax/javascript.vim` and test again. (see `:help after-directory`)

Comment: It's actually `.vim`. My mistake. It's not `.js`. Updated question. @Ralf

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to do it on an empty noname buffer with `vim -u NONE`

I have copied (only changed function to title hl group) your lines and executed them, as you can see on a screenshot, it works without `.` in `iskeyword`:

[image]

PS:

To execute those commands type/copy them to `:`.

I use my own plugin to eval vimscript :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your problem. But here is what I would do:

Create the file `~/.vim/after/syntax/javascript.vim` and add you configuration to it:

```
syntax match myMatch "\v\.\zs\w+\ze\("
highlight link myMatch Function
```

This syntax file it then an extension to the default javascript syntax file of Vim.

Vim first loads the default syntax file `syntax/javascript.vim` from the runtimepath. After that it looks for `after/syntax/javascript.vim` (also via runtimepath). If found, this is loaded also.

See `:help mysyntaxfile-add`, `:help after-directory` and `:help runtimepath`.

To display you current runtimepath execute:

```
set runtimepath?
```

PS: If you really want to do that via Pathogen, you also could create the file as `~/.vim/bundle/vim-javascript-syn/after/syntax/javascript.vim`.